# Zeeman effect, fine structure, hyperfine structure etc and the Spectral splitting

Tags: quantum-mechanics, atomic-physics, spectroscopy

I am currently studying in atom physics the different "ways" you can "produce" spectral splitting of an atom. But because this is new stuff to me, i find most of it a bit complicated and confusing.
So i would really like for someone to be able to give me a detailed explanation ( a summary) of all these cases.(if it is something that it takes time to write or elaborate, links which give me an explanation of these things that i would like to know are also appreciated, **each of the question is very very important**). ESPECIALLY I WOULD LIKE for a given n (for example n =3) a  **graphics** comparison of the different splitting for each case. The cases are the following ones :

1 - Fine structure splitting.
How does it occur? How do we prepare "devices" to produce this kind of splitting?
For an atom with multiple electrons when we speak about fine structure splitting do we study this effect for each individual electron (that means for a set of quantum numbers n,l,m,s) or we can also study the fine structure splitting of the whole atom?
Formula for energy level, what is it?

2 - Hyper-fine structure splitting.
How do we make this type of splitting happen.
I know that it the case when we consider the nucleus and the electron spins. What happens with the orbital angular momentum? Do we simply ignore it?
Can we transit from fine stucture splitting to hyper fine one ? What i mean can we for example for n=3 do the fine splitting and then follow it up for with the hyper fine one?

3 - Zeeman effect. (orbital Zeeman effect, spin Zeeman effect, spin-orbital Zeeman effect).
When does it happen? Does the Zeeman effect change if the magnetic field is weak or strong and if in each case (weak or strong) it is also homogeneous or non-homogeneous

4 - LS- Coupling.
This type of coupling if i am not mistaken gives or produces a type of splitting.
How is it different from the Zeeman effect ?

5 - jj - coupling.
When does it happen? How is it different from the Zeeman effect ?

6 - Paschen - Back effect.
I understand this type of splitting.i Think it is the easiest  form to understand. One basically for each case of orbital magnetic quantum number m_l = -l ....+l takes into account each spin case for an electron.

7 - Linear Stark effect.
I know that this type of splitting happens under the influence of an electric field in comparison to the Zeeman effect.

8 - Quadratic Stark effect.

9 - Dynamic Stark effect.
Can the dynamic Stark effect be linear or quadratic ?

For all the above cases my most important questions are  :

1 - In which case, for us in order to graphically (with a sketch) represent  a type of splitting, we study an electron of an atom and in which case it is enough to study the whole atom. This question might be a bit difficult to understand, so let me try and explain it with an example :

for fine structure splitting which is the combination of spin and orbital momentum of an electron in order to sketch this splitting we are studying an electron of an atom. Not the atom.
For another type of splitting maybe we don't need to study its electrons but it is sufficient to simply study the whole atom. I hope this helps.
what i mean with sketch : (https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/1/17/Fine_hyperfine_levels.svg)

2 - **The most important question of all** :
For each of the above listed cases i would like a graphic comparison of all of them for example n=3.

Links with detailed explanation of my questions would also help. But the graphics comparison is what i really need.

Comment: These are a *lot* of questions.

Comment: The result of multiple questions not answered in our classes. I have tried for quite sometime now to find answers and to logically compare each case with the rest and i have failed.

Comment: The internet is full of texts that answer pretty much all of your questions. Griffiths, Sakuri, Bohm, Ryder and many more fine textbooks are available with appropriate searches. I think you should consult these sources before posting such a long list of questions.  If you don't follow a particular explanation, then you could post a specific question here. If you search this site, you will find recommended textbooks and answers related to your question.

Comment: One of the reasons for closing questions on this site is “Needs more focus: This question currently includes multiple questions in one. It should focus on one problem only.” Your question is likely to get closed unless you quickly narrow it. What you are asking could easily take up many dozens of pages in a textbook.

Answer (score 4):

> ESPECIALLY I WOULD LIKE for a given n (for example n =3) a graphics
> comparison of the different splitting for each case.

Unless you specify which atom you want, and provide spectroscopic data for the constants before the $\mathbf{L}\cdot\mathbf{S}$ and $\mathbf{I}\cdot\mathbf{J}$ terms for that specific atom & isotope, we cannot help you.

#### Definition

Fine structure and Hyperfine structure do not necessarily refer to a specific physical phenomenon that is causing them. They refer to *order* of the energy correction that they entail. See the table below:

\begin{array}{|c|c|}
\hline
\text{contribution} & \text{energy scale} \\
\hline
\text{gross structure} & \sim \alpha^2 mc^2 \\
\text{fine structure} & \sim \alpha^4 mc^2 \\
\text{hyperfine structure} & \sim \alpha^4 m/m_p \\
\text{Lamb shift} &  \sim \alpha^5 \ln(\alpha) mc^2\\  
\hline
\end{array}

*Caption for the above*:
Energy scales, $m$ is the mass of the electron, $m_p$ of the proton, $\alpha$ the fine-structure constant that sets the scale.

Based on this, for simple atoms the fine structure is given by spin-orbit coupling, relativistic corrections, and the Darwin term. Because they all give yo a $\propto \alpha^4$ correction. 
 On the other hand, the hyperfine structure is given by the nuclear-electronic interaction, and the electric quadrupole correction to the nucleus (i.e. a correction to the nucleus not being a simple point charge). 
 The nucleus-electron interaction is essentially a magnetic dipole correction. You could also work out a magnetic octupole correction which would have an even smaller energy scale (so you coin your own "ultra"fine structure régime) but, as far as I know, this shift has not been measured for standard alkali atoms like Rb and K.

#### Questions

> 1 - Fine structure splitting. How does it occur? How do we prepare
> "devices" to produce this kind of splitting? For an atom with multiple
> electrons when we speak about fine structure splitting do we study
> this effect for each individual electron (that means for a set of
> quantum numbers n,l,m,s) or we can also study the fine structure
> splitting of the whole atom? Formula for energy level, what is it?

As per the definitions above, a "device" that would cause a fine structure splitting should introduce an interacting causing an energy shift on the order $\alpha^4 mc^2$.

Usually, however, when people talk about fine structure they 99% of the time mean spin-orbit coupling. I.e. the interaction between the magnetic field generated by the orbital motion of the electron ($\mathbf{L}$, essentially a current) and the magnetic field generated by its spin ($\mathbf{S}$). Hence the name spin-orbit coupling, and the usual $\mathbf{L}\cdot\mathbf{S}$ term.

For multi-electron atoms, it's up to your assumptions (nuclear charge, screening, external fields etc.) which quantum numbers are "good" based on which interactions dominate. In weak external fields, for instance, you can use $LS$ coupling (where $L$ and $S$ are the sum of the individual $\ell$ and $s$ of each electron), while in strong fields you should use $jj$ coupling (i.e. treating each electron separately). More about this in your question below.

The formula depends on the atom, its structure, and the régime you are interested in.

> 2 - Hyper-fine structure splitting. How do we make this type of
> splitting happen. I know that it the case when we consider the nucleus
> and the electron spins. What happens with the orbital angular
> momentum? Do we simply ignore it? Can we transit from fine stucture
> splitting to hyper fine one ? What i mean can we for example for n=3
> do the fine splitting and then follow it up for with the hyper fine
> one?

Same as before. even though the hyperfine structure also includes the electric quadrupole correction, people usually mean the interaction between the nuclear magnetic moment (given by orbital motion of the nucleons and their spins) $\mathbf{I}$ and the total electronic angular momentum $\mathbf{J} = \mathbf{L} + \mathbf{S}$. Hence the usual term $\mathbf{I}\cdot\mathbf{J}$.

"What happens with the orbital angular momentum? Do we simply ignore it?". No! $\mathbf{J}$ also contains the orbital motion of the electron.

For an $n=3$ example, we need to know which $\ell$, $s$ you have. For instance in $\ell=0, s = 1/2$, you have no splittings.

> 3 - Zeeman effect. (orbital Zeeman effect, spin Zeeman effect,
> spin-orbital Zeeman effect). When does it happen? Does the Zeeman
> effect change if the magnetic field is weak or strong and if in each
> case (weak or strong) it is also homogeneous or non-homogeneous

The Zeeman effect is the generic term for the splitting of spectral lines in the presence of an *external* (i.e. not caused by the electron or the nucleus) static magnetic field $\mathbf{B}$.

If you do the maths for a uniform field, introducing the canonical momentum $\mathbf{p} \rightarrow \mathbf{p} + q\mathbf{A}$ with $\mathbf{A}$ being the vector potential, you find that the Hamiltonian of your atom gains two extra terms:

$$
H = \dots \underbrace{\frac{q}{2m}(\mathbf{L}\cdot \mathbf{B})}_{\mathrm{Linear\,\,Zeeman\,\,effect}}+\underbrace{\frac{q^2\mathbf{B}^2}{8m}(x^2+y^2)}_{\mathrm{Quadratic\,\,Zeeman\,\,effect}},
$$

where $\mathbf{L}$ is actually a placeholder for any type of angular momentum. See formulae below.

The quadratic Zeeman effect is usually ignored unless in atoms where the linear one is zero, and/or in extremely high fields.

The external field couples to any internal magnetic field, generated by any form of angular momentum (spin, orbital, nuclear etc.):

\begin{equation}
\begin{gathered}
H_{\mathrm{Zeeman}} = \mu_{\mathrm{B}} (g_S\mathbf{S} + g_L\mathbf{L} + g_I\mathbf{I})\cdot\mathbf{B}, \\ 
H_{\mathrm{Zeeman}} = \mu_{\mathrm{B}} (g_J\mathbf{J} + g_I\mathbf{I})\cdot\mathbf{B}, \\
H_{\mathrm{Zeeman}} = \mu_{\mathrm{B}} g_F \mathbf{F}\cdot\mathbf{B},
\end{gathered}
\end{equation}

It once again depends on which régime you are working in, which quantum numbers are "good" and hence of the above expressions you should use.

> 4 - LS- Coupling. This type of coupling if i am not mistaken gives or
> produces a type of splitting. How is it different from the Zeeman
> effect ?

$LS$ coupling is just a way to combine the individual orbital $\ell_i$ and spin $s_i$ angular momenta in a multi-electron atom. $L = \sum_i \ell_i$ and $S = \sum_i s_i$. Then $J = |L - S|, ... L + S$. And you can use $J$ as the total angular momentum. The validity of the $LS$ coupling scheme relies on the individual $\ell_i$ and $s_i$ precessing about the total values $L$ and $S$ and not about an external magnetic field - rephrasing that, it relies on the external field being weaker than the characteristic energy scale in this case.

In case of a strong enough field, each $\ell_i$ and $s_i$ will couple to $B$ strongly and hence it does not make sense to sum the $\ell_i$ together. But you do $jj$ coupling (next).

> 5 - jj - coupling. When does it happen? How is it different from the
> Zeeman effect ?

It has nothing to do with the Zeeman effect. The Zeeman effect just cares about $J\cdot B$, while the $LS$ and $jj$ coupling schemes are different ways of working out $J$.

If the magnetic field is strong, each electron couples to it strongly. So you cannot assume that the total $L = \sum_i \ell_i$ is a good quantum number anymore (it would be if no other interaction were competing for how the $\ell_i$ should align themselves to minimise energy). The $jj$ coupling scheme basically says that you work out the total angular momentum *per electron* $j_i = \ell_i + s_i$, and then sum them: $J = \sum_i j_i$.

See for instance [here](https://users.aber.ac.uk/ruw/teach/327/lsjj.php) and [here](http://hyperphysics.phy-astr.gsu.edu/hbase/quantum/vecmod.html).

> 6 - Paschen - Back effect. I understand this type of splitting.i Think
> it is the easiest form to understand. One basically for each case of
> orbital magnetic quantum number m_l = -l ....+l takes into account
> each spin case for an electron.

Depending on the strength of the external magnetic field, different quantum numbers become good or bad. This identifies régimes in which you call the splittings some name, be it Zeeman or Paschen-Back. Summary below:

[image]

> 7 - Linear Stark effect. I know that this type of splitting happens
> under the influence of an electric field in comparison to the Zeeman
> effect.

Great so you've already answered your question. It's the same thing as the linear Zeeman effect from before, just with $\mathbf{E}$ instead of $\mathbf{B}$.

*Static* external electic field.

> 8 - Quadratic Stark effect.

This is a it confusing in terms of terminology. The term *quadratic* refers to both the second-order perturbation theory correction to the linear Start effect (i.e. an interaction term linear with $\mathbf{E}$), and to the interaction with a term that goes as $\mathbf{E}^2$ (like the intensity of light $I$).

You can read [here](http://farside.ph.utexas.edu/teaching/qmech/Quantum/node104.html) how these two things are connected by just *defining* the polarisability $\alpha$ of the atom as the second-order pertubration theory coefficient. So that an interaction term that goes like the intensity $I$ is written $\propto 
\alpha I$ and is equivalent to working with $\mathbf{E}$. The reason second-order perturbation theory is needed is because neutral atoms with
no permanent electric dipole moment (and hence with an inversion symmetry $\mathbf{r} \rightarrow −\mathbf{r}$) have no first-order Stark shift.

> 9 - Dynamic Stark effect. Can the dynamic Stark effect be linear or
> quadratic ?

The dynamic Stark effect is the same thing as the static Stark effect (see questions 8 and 9), but for a time-varying field. So you will see people will write stuff like $\langle \mathbf{p}\cdot \mathbf{E} \rangle$ where $\langle \rangle$ is the temporal average. This assumes that the characteristic timescale of the atom is much higher than the variation of the external field, so that it only sees an averaged/steady-state effect.

This is used in optical traps for cold atoms.

Comment: @G.Smith I changed all of them apart from the last table which I didn't manage to write in MathJax. I could do it in Latex but not all commands are supported here.

Comment: Thank you for the edit.

Comment: SuperCiocia thank you for your answer.I will read it. Thank you

Comment: But why is it not possible to have a graphics representation of each case for n=3 ? And lets say for an atom with 30 electrones?

Comment: It certainly is. I have made these plots before, diagonalising the Hamiltonian in the angular momentum basis. But you need to provide spectroscopic data for the fine and hyperfine structure terms, along with what the screened coulomb potential looks like etc. That is if you want it for a real atom. Otherwise you can easily tell how each $\ell$ is split in the $n=3$ by combining it with $s$. But you need to know how many electrons there are in that orbital. All this is all at zero field. So summarising: tell us which atom and/or which electronic configuration (like 1s2 2s2 2p6 3s) you have.

Comment: Ok, thank you for the lengthy explanation

Comment: @Dari none of your >12 questions have an accepted answer. If and when you feel like an answer satisfies your question, accept it. Otherwise it keeps showing in the 'unanswered' section of the given tags.

Comment: How do i do that?

Comment: Next to answers there are up and down arrows for upvotes and downvotes, and a check mark for accepting the answer.